# Angular reactive form validity with dynamic form group controls

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

I have an angular reactive form in which I am listening to `valueChanges` for only a valid form state. However, I also need to listen to `valueChanges` on my form control and add/remove controls depending on the value. The problem is that when I change the value of control my formGroup subscription is triggering because technically the form is still valid until the controls have been added. How do I make the formGroup subscription wait until the controls have been added?

```
    this.formGroup
      .get('control')?.valueChanges
      .subscribe(value => {
        this.removeControls();
        this.addControls(value);
      });

    this.formGroup.valueChanges.pipe(
      filter(_ => this.formGroup.valid)
    ).subscribe(values => this.update(values));
```

Comment: You could use Angular's Cross-Field Validation to validate the new fields exist: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#cross-field-validation

Comment: This worked for me. Do you want to add an answer so I can accept and give you credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Angular's Cross-Field Validation to validate the new fields exist: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#cross-field-validation